# Развертывание проекта на CakePHP

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp

При развертывании проекта на CakePHP в XAMPP столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php:174 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(92): ExceptionRenderer->_getController(Object(FatalErrorException)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(126): ExceptionRenderer->__construct(Object(FatalErrorException)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(274): ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(213): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 30) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(933): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 30, Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(906): App::_checkFatalError() #6 [internal function]: App::shutdown() #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs...\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php on line 174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую перейти от XAMPP на Open Server: https://ospanel.io/
Ошибок может быть много из за сервера, а XAMPP работает только с одной версией PHP и чтобы сменить версию, надо скачивать весь XAMPP с нуля. А в Open Server есть все модули, все версии, переключай, проверяй. Если ошибки при развертывании, то значит проблема в 90% случаев с настройкой сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ это использовать встроенный веб-сервер PHP. В CakePHP 3 его запустить проще простого. Смотрите в документации https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ru/installation.html#php